# Can phpBB receive posts sent by email?

Tags: phpbb

I mean if is it possible to use phpBB like a mailing-list: sending a new e-mail creates new forum topic, responding to an existing e-mail creates comment to an existing forum topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible out of box, but there is a Modification (Mod) available for it here for phpbb 3.0 or nigher:

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=603719

Comment: Unfortunately the referred-to mod (mail2forum) has been abandoned.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this Mod has been abandoned. In addition to this with the release of PHPBB 3.1.x all Mods created for prior version of PHPBB (3.0.x or lower) will become useless, so this will no longer work, unless the author of the mod decides to upgrade his mod to an "Extension".